# SSAS cube and getting data with MDX for SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssas, olap, olap-cube

I'm new to OLAP cubes. Can you directed in the right direction with small example.

Let's say I have table "transactions" with 3 columns: transaction_id (int), date (datetime), amount (decimal(16,2)).

I want to create a cube and then get data with MDX query for SSRS report.
I want report to show something like:
[image]

Ok. I know i can have fact table with amount and date dimention (date->month->year).

Can you explain what to do in order to get this result (including how to write MDX query). Thanks.

---

Can someone explain why I get amount of full 201504 and 201606 months even if I specified exact range with days?

```
SELECT
     [Measures].[Amount] ON COLUMNS
    ,[Dim_Date].[Hierarchy].[Month].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM
    [DM]
WHERE
    (
       {[Dim_Date].[Date Int].&[20150414] : [Dim_Date].[Date Int].&[20160615]}
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below, change the query accordingly :)

```
SELECT  
    { [Date].[EnglishMonthName].[EnglishMonthName]} ON COLUMNS,  
    { [Date].[DateHierarchy].[Year].&[2015],   
        [Date].[DateHierarchy].[Year].&[2016] } ON ROWS  
FROM [YourCubeName]
WHERE ([Measures].[amount])
```

Comment: Ok thanks for sample. I wrote a query it works but not as I expected (see main post)

Comment: Because [Dim_Date].[Hierarchy].[Month].MEMBERS includes ALL, and it will give you the full month no matter what you specified. Instead you should use [Dim_Date].[Hierarchy].[Month].[Month]

Answer (score 0):

So you want someone to show you how to create a multi-dimensional cube from scratch and report on it in a single answer...? Start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170208.aspx) and work through the lessons